# Is it possible to use a Gradle config variable in my gitlab-ci file?

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was wondering if it is possible to use the versionName variable in the DefaultConfig of my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

In my gitlab-ci file:

```
stages:
    - build

release:
  stage: build
  only:
    - release
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease
    # Here I need to use the value of versionName in my gradle file.
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing it with a command line script in the gitlab-ci file:

```
export VERSION = $(grep -E "versionName " app/build.gradle | cut -d "\"" -f2)
```

This way I can access the versionName with $VERSION inside the file.