# Save gradle command result into a variable in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: bash, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to save gradle-based project's version into a variable in gitlab-ci script. In my `build.gradle` I have:

```
tasks.register('version') {
    doLast {
        println(version)
    }
}
```

It reads `version` from `gradle.properties` (let's say `version=0.1`) and returns it.

I execute it as `gradlew version -q` so I get only result, with no unnecessary output. When using unix-style variable creation of command result, that is: `version=$(./gradlew version -q)`, the runner ends script. Is it possible to save the output into a variable for script?

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: gradle:jdk11

cache: &wrapper
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - chmod a+x gradlew

stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - deploy

wrapper:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - gradle wrapper

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/classes/**
      - build/libs/*.jar
  cache:
    <<: *wrapper
    policy: pull

properties:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - eval version=$(./gradlew version -q)
    - echo $version # not even called
```

I also tried to omit `eval` to have `version=$(./gradlew version -q)` in `script`, but nothing changes.

CI output:

```
$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
$ chmod a+x gradlew
$ version=$(./gradlew version -q)
Cleaning up file based variables
```

Comment: Try it without the `eval`? So just `version=$(./gradlew version -q)`? It sounds like `eval` returns the exit code of the expression being evaluated, so your script is doing a
```bash
version=$(./gradlew version -q)
exit $?
```

Comment: @AdamMarshall tried also, it results int exactly the same behavior

Comment: Ah ok, hopefully someone else will know more.

Comment: how do you reference artifact files in subsequent jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. I mustn't use variable, simply. It's needed to directly pass evaluation to another command, using double quotes, like:

`.gitlab-ci.yml` (part):

```
properties:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$(./gradlew version -q)"
```

It started to work

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you. Much prefer this to grep-ing the file looking for a the version ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752984/is-it-possible-to-use-a-gradle-config-variable-in-my-gitlab-ci-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124873/how-to-get-versionname-versioncode-from-kotlin-dsl-gradle-file-in-gitlab-ci-scri